# How to simplify Splunk search with duplicated query statements

Tags: splunk

I wrote the following Splunk search that I plan to use for an alert:

```
 index=* earliest=-1h source="*video-bic*.log" "Get video" |
 dedup videoid | stats list(videoid) as l_videoid | 
 appendcols [search index=* earliest=-1h source="*video-bic*.log" "Get video" |
 dedup videoid | stats count(videoid) as num_msgs] | 
 table num_msgs, l_videoid
```

It works but I would like to simplify it, so that I don't have to repeat this part of the query twice:

```
 index=* earliest=-1h source="*video-bic*.log" "Get video"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The `stats` command accepts multiple arguments.

```
index=* earliest=-1h source="*video-bic*.log" "Get video" 
| stats values(videoid) as l_videoid, dc(videoid) as num_msgs
| table num_msgs, l_videoid
```

For better efficiency, I removed the `dedup` command and replaced the `list` and `count` functions with `values` and `dc` (distinct_count), respectively.